# Remove class from all child elements and add class on parent/parent of clicked Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Background:** What I am trying to accomplish. When a user clicks any of the radio inputs inside the div with the class `corp-struct` I want to add the following class to that elements parent element two levels up. So (in the example below) not `<label>` but `<div class="radio radio-primary radio-button">` But before that happens I want to remove this same class from any div's located inside of the corp-struct element.

Everything but removing the class names from the other children div's is working.

```
let $e = $(e.currentTarget);
if ( $e.hasClass('checked-radio-button')){
$e.parent().parent().removeClass('checked-radio-button')
} else {

$("div#corp-struct>div.radio-button").removeClass('checked-radio-button');
$e.parent().parent().addClass('checked-radio-button');

}
```

**QUESTION:**  I only want to add the above class to that element if it has not already been added. At the same time I want to make sure to remove the class from the other 3 elements inside of  `<div id="corp-struct" class="radio-group container-fluid">` finally if I click on a radio that already has the class make sure to remove it from that one.

```
**HTML EXAMPLE:**

<div class="radio-group container-fluid corp-struct">
                    <h6>Page Title</h6>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="radio radio-primary radio-button">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="corpStructure" id="corpStructure_subset" value="subset" {{#eq corpStructure "subset"}}checked{{/eq}}></input>
                                    <span class="circle"></span>
                                    <span class="check"></span>
                                    <span class="radio-button-text">{{nls "organization_corpStructure_subset"}}-{{corpStructure}}</span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="radio radio-primary radio-button">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="corpStructure" id="corpStructure_subsidiary" value="subsidiary"></input>
                                    <span class="circle"></span>
                                    <span class="check"></span>
                                    <span class="radio-button-text">{{nls "organization_corpStructure_subsidiary"}}</span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="radio radio-primary radio-button">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="corpStructure" id="corpStructure_single" value="single"></input>
                                    <span class="circle"></span>
                                    <span class="check"></span>
                                    <span class="radio-button-text">{{nls "organization_corpStructure_single"}}</span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="radio radio-primary radio-button">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="corpStructure" id="corpStructure_parent" value="parent"></input>
                                    <span class="circle"></span>
                                    <span class="check"></span>
                                    <span class="radio-button-text">{{nls "organization_corpStructure_parent"}}</span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**My results so far:**

When I click on a radio the class is added correctly and if I click on it again it is removed correctly. But If I click on one and then click on the second one instead of number 1 having the class removed they both have the class now.

Comment: What would be `e.currentTarget`? The div or the radio button?

Comment: Post a working fiddle!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir here I made him a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gfz7zupn/)

Comment: I ended up answering my own question with  $("#corp-struct").find("*").removeClass("checked-radio-button");  which may not be the best solution but it works for now.

Comment: thank you @zgood for creating that.

Comment: @Denoteone do you want to remove the class from the element if it was clicked again?

Comment: Yes which is what the first part of the if statement should be doing.

Comment: @Denoteone then you should use `checkboxes` not `radio buttons`!

Comment: @Denoteone hope this is useful: https://jsfiddle.net/0kr5zacf/!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your problem correctly you should be able to do something like this:

```
var $e = $(e.currentTarget),
    $div = $e.closest('div.radio-button'),
    $container = $e.closest('.corp-struct');

    $div.toggleClass('checked-radio-button');

    $('div.radio-button.checked-radio-button', $container).not($div).removeClass('checked-radio-button');
```

So to break it down....

Get a jQuery object reference of the clicked radio button:

```
var $e = $(e.currentTarget)
```

Then a reference of that radio buttons containing div (`closest` will navigate up the DOM tree until it finds the first element with the provided selector. I changed it to this in case your DOM structure changes in the future where `.parent().parent()` might fail):

```
$div = $e.closest('div.radio-button')
```

Then a reference of the overall `.corp-struct` container:

```
$container = $e.closest('.corp-struct');
```

Now toggle the class of the container div:

```
$div.toggleClass('checked-radio-button');
```

And lastly remove that class from any other divs inside the `$container` that are **not** this div

```
$('div.radio-button.checked-radio-button', $container).not($div).removeClass('checked-radio-button');
```

Make sense?

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gfz7zupn/2/) for a demo